# Vibrational model for nuclear intrinsic excitations

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why do the diagonal matrix elements always vanish in the vibrational model of a nucleus (say, harmonic vibrationss) but they can be non-zero in the rotational limit? Would they be non-zero in the anharmonic limit?

Comment: Hi Ana, sorry but which matrix are you talking about? Also, by "rotational limit" do you mean the rigid rotor model?

Comment: yes yes, sorry i meant rotational model.

Comment: Also, I am talking about the matrix element of the potential operator of a vibrational nucleus